# Vertically aligning text on top of a scalable image

Tags: css

I created an example here of what's trying to be accomplished: http://codepen.io/blkedy/pen/mtqxa

Basically I would like the text "Your name" to bottom align with the full-scale pinkish/red image behind it. The image will be full scale adjusting width/height upon browser size.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.row {position:relative;}
```

Just give this to `.row` and you are done.

Comment: Strange, working fine for me. why doesn't just giving `position: absolute` and `bottom:0px` doesn't work in this case? any idea?

Comment: The OP already set his `h1` with `position:absolute` and `bottom:0`, however the parent container (which has the class `row`) should have `position:absolute` or `position:relative` so that the `h1` position takes effect. that's the reason, I don't know why you mentioned `no height attribute` here.